# Prove the infinite product topology where each factor are compact subspace of [0,1] is a compact space

Tags: general-topology

"If $(X_i,\tau_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, are compact subspaces of $[0,1]$, deduce from Theorem 9.3.8 and Exercises 9.2 #1, that $\Pi(X_i,\tau_i)$ is compact."

Theorem 9.3.8 is the hilbert cube is compact. Exercise 9.2 #1 is that the infinite product of closed sets is a closed set in the product topology.

So every compact subspace of $[0,1]$ are simply closed intervals in $[0,1]$ and closed intervals are all homeomorphic to each other. So we have an infinite product where each factor is homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ which is by definition the Hilbert Cube so that is a compact space.

Now I did not had to use the fact that the infinite product of closed sets is a closed set in the product topology, which I think I'm suppose to use. Is there a mistake in my logic?

Comment: Compact subspaces of $[0,1]$ need not be intervals. Isn't $\{0,1\}$ a compact set?

Comment: oh yes that is true, every singleton is compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kavi pointed out in the comments, it is not true that all compact subsets of $[0,1]$ are closed intervals.

What you can use is that since $(X_i,\tau_i)$ are compact subspaces of the compact set $[0,1]$, they are closed.
So, by Exercise 9.2 #1, $\Pi_i(X_i,\tau_i)$ is closed.
Then, by compactess of the Hilbert cube, any closed subset is also compact.

By the way, it is true that any product of compact topological spaces is compact in the product topology - this is called Tychonoff's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The two facts combined tell us that $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N^+} X_n$ is a closed subset of $\prod_{n \in \Bbb N^+} [0,1]$, which is compact. $X_i$ can be much more general than a closed interval, like middle third Cantor set, any finite subset or a convergent sequence with limit, e.g. So this fact is more general than the Hilbert cube fact.

And in general, a closed subspace of a compact space is compact. That’s the complete proof.

The general Tychonoff theorem is only discussed later in the text, but this would have been an immediate consequence of it.

Comment: Yeah the general Tychonoff theorem is not proven at this point and that would have make this problem trivial. So I think we were suppose to use the fact that the infinite product [0,1] is the hilbert cube which is compact.

Comment: @willyx888 yes and the closed subspace fact.